# Set and Get Global Environment variables using PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I have created simple PHP scripts to set and get environment variables.

set.php

```
putenv("TEST_VAR=HelloWorld");
```

get.php

```
echo getenv('TEST_VAR');
```

But I do not get any output after executing get.php

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. 
I also tried to set env variable using shell script.

test.sh

```
export TEST_VAR=HelloWorld
```

And tried getting it using get.php. But I always get it blank.

Is there anything else I need to add or modify in my script.
Or are there any config changes need to be done.

Comment: Have you tried setting `getenv()` second param `local_only` to `true` - _to only return local environment variables (set by the operating system or putenv)_ ([manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) ).

Comment: yes, I tried that as well. Still blank output.

Comment: Variable of `putenv` exists only during the script execution.

Comment: @u_mulder But I want to set env globally, so that I can use it overall in my application.

Answer (score 1):

setenv() and getenv() only work inside the same script, and are usefull when you want to diferrentiate from an environment variable for one specific script.

To store information in between of requests, you'll need some form of storage. Which one depends on your use case.

## Cache / in-memory storage

If you want to temporary store the information, the retrieval needs to be fast, and it isn't a problem if the data get's lost, you can use a in memory storage.

You have multiple possibilities like Redis and Memcached. I wouldn't advice APCu because it is no longer actively developed.

## Persistant storage

You can store your data to disk. This is slower then in-memory storage, but data is far less likely to get lost.

You can use file storage:

set.php

```php
<?php

file_put_contents('data/my.dat', 'My data');
```

get.php

```php
<?php

echo file_get_contents('data/my.dat');
```

Or you can use a database.

## Session storage

You often want to store data that is specific for one user. Other users see different data. You can use php sessions to achieve that.

Example of using PHP sessions:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

## Environment variables

If you insist on using environment variables, and want to change them on runtime, you can use [phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) and write to .env files. Please note that environment variables should be used for software configuration, not as a storage pattern.